# eclipselink moxy json external binding for anonymous array

Tags: json, eclipselink, moxy

How should I be unmarshalling an anonymous array formatted json input. I tried the following but sets object fields as null. Just note that it's not complete code, and the records unmarshalling is on separate json binding that works fine.

Json input:

```
{
records:[ [1,"test"], [2,"test2"]]
}
```

Unmarshalling to an object using array elements using external binding

```
{
    "package-name": "com.model",
    "xmlns" : "http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm",
    "version" : "2.1",
   "java-types" : {
      "java-type" : [ {
         "name" : "WeekBox",
         "xml-root-element" : {},
         "java-attributes" : {
            "xml-element" : [ 
              {"java-attribute" : "id" , "xml-path" : "[0]/text()"},
                {"java-attribute" : "title" , "xml-path" : "[1]/text()"}
            ]
         }
      } ]
   }
}
```

Model Object:

```
public class WeekBox {
private Integer id;
private String title;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) does not currently support nested arrays.  You can use the following link to track our progress on adding this capability:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/389815